# css code dont shows on server

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I have a loading img that I want to show in the middle of the screen but it just comes up over the rest of by stuff. Here is the css code i use

```
#overlay {
position: fixed;
z-index: 99;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
filter: Alpha(Opacity=90);
opacity: 0.9;
-moz-opacity: 0.9;
}            
#theprogress {
background-color: #fff;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding:10px;
width: 300px;
height: 30px;
line-height:30px;
text-align: center;
filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
-moz-opacity: 1;
}
#modalprogress {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
margin: -11px 0 0 -150px;
color: #990000;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:14px;
}
```

it works in visual studio 2010 but not when i put it up on the server

Comment: What do you mean with it comes over the rest of your stuff?

Comment: it puss the rest down and put in the top

Comment: I propose you post your html as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you, and if I did, I would provide the following answer:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        ....
</head>
```

I had some issues with CSS recently where everything was running fine on my machine but when I deployed on the server, even in running it in a same-version browser, I got a different HTML.

So I placed this meta tag in my `head` section of the HTML and everything ran fine.

YOu could also try:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Hope it helps,